# Google App Engine NDB - Cursor on query working on local dev but not in production

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I have an issue. I call a query with a cursor which is set to the Cursor() first time around. I fetch 50 items from the query

```
qry = cls.query(cls.store == store_id, cls.user != exclude_user, cls.active == True, cls.offline == False).order(cls.user, cls._key, -cls.created)
```

I return that qry to the calling class and run the following fetch

```
result, next_cursor, more = qry.fetch_page(pagination, start_cursor=cursor)
```

This works no problem, I then do the following with the cursor and pass it back to the client as per the docs:

```
client_params['next_page'] = next_cursor.urlsafe()
```

I have logged this cursor to make sure it is the same on the return call to the server, which it is

I get it thus:

```
cursor = Cursor(urlsafe=page)
```

However the second attempt to retrieve the next 50 or less items always results in the following error:

```
BadRequestError: cursor position is outside the range of the original query
```

Now this whole process works fine on the local development machine but not in production

Comment: Can you dump your query object in both cases? In order for cursor to work properly, the other parameters should exactly be the same

Comment: The query is exactly the same on both occasions. I'll get five minutes later I'll dump it and add it to the question

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your trouble comes from the `cls.user != exclude_user` query parameter.

From [Limitations of cursors](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/datastore/query-cursors#limitations_of_cursors) (yes, I known it's in the superseded `db` documentation, but I'm pretty sure it applies to `ndb` as well - same limitations [are present in java as well](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/datastore/query-cursors#limitations_of_cursors), they're likely on the datastore side, not on the client library side):

> - Because the `!=` and `IN` operators are implemented with multiple queries, queries that use them do not support cursors.

To confirm try to drop that query parameter.

As for why it happens only in production - the development server emulation probably doesn't cover this details.

Comment: straight out of the Google docs: Some NDB queries don't support query cursors, but you can fix them. If a query uses IN, OR, or !=, then the query results won't work with cursors unless ordered by key. If an application doesn't order the results by key and calls fetch_page(), it gets a BadArgumentError. If User.query(User.name.IN(['Joe', 'Jane'])).order(User.name).fetch_page(N) gets an error, change it to User.query(User.name.IN(['Joe', 'Jane'])).order(User.name, User.key).fetch_page(N)

Comment: That implies to me that you can use cursors as long as you order by key and of course with the inequality operator you have to list that first in the order...

Comment: Anyway, I changed it to work a different slightly less efficient way by iterating over the query set and filtering the user manually rather than on query...